# Trying to match strings from multiple columns and create pair list where matches are found

Tags: r, string

I have two data frames with string values:

```
df1 <- data.frame(values = c("apples_x", "oranges_z", "bananas_y", "berries_u", "melons_r"))

df2 = data.frame(values  = c('apples','oranges','z','pears','x','bananas','plums','y','h','grapes','q'))
```

I would like to perform a pairwise comparison between both data frames, by iterating over every row of data frame 2 and assigning pair numbers where both fruit and letter of df1 value appears in df2.
I want to create a new data frame that stores the pair numbers for the matches found.
Ideally it would look something like this:

```
df3 %>% head()
  values  paired
  <ch>     <int>
1 apples      1         
2 x           1          
3 oranges     2          
4 z           2          
5 bananas     3          
6 y           3
```

I tried to separate the values in df1 into two strings, but I am getting back strings with matches on any character.

```
lapply(df2, FUN=function(x){any(df1==x[[1]] & df1==x[[2]])})
```

Comment: I've edited your code to inlcude the data as a data.frame, which is what the text suggests. Please edit it back if that's not right.

Comment: How do you get `2` for `oranges`? (For example.)

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of indexing.  Then `df1 %>% mutate(paired = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(values)` as others commented, the count of matches from the example is not giving the expected output

Comment: My apologies, I have edited the post for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the update, we may `filter` after splitting the column in 'df1', then create a sequence index and reshape to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1  %>% 
  separate(values, into = c('values1', 'values2')) %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ .x %in% df2$values)) %>%
  mutate(paired = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -paired, values_to = 'value', names_to = NULL) %>%
  select(value, paired)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  value   paired
  <chr>    <int>
1 apples       1
2 x            1
3 oranges      2
4 z            2
5 bananas      3
6 y            3
```